# Using cell styles provided by the ss model in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-2007, excel-2003

I trying to make the code I already wrote for an XSSF workbook compatible to both xls and xlsx. Given below a piece of code as an example.

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("F:\\JavaEE\\test.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

short cellBorderColour = IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex();

Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE_GREY.index);

CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
cellStyle.setFont(font);

cellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_HAIR);
cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(cellBorderColour);
cellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_HAIR);
cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(cellBorderColour);
cellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_HAIR);
cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(cellBorderColour);
cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(cellBorderColour);

Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
Cell cell = row.createCell(1);

sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, 4));
borderRowCells(1, 4, row, cell, cellStyle);
cell.setCellValue("Value");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("F:\\JavaEE\\new_test.xls");
workbook.write(fos);

//Take care of exception handling and closing of the stream.
```

The utility method as used by the above code to border across merged cells.

```
private void borderRowCells(int from, int to, Row row, Cell cell, CellStyle cellStyle) {
    for (int i = from; i <= to; ++i) {
        cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
}
```

This code is meant to apply some borders in conjunction with other styles across some merged cells.

The border across merged cells is however, not applied correctly as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

The borders are expected to be applied starting from `B2` to `E2`. The actual border area however, covers only from `C2` to `E2`

The cell value `Value` is also not aligned center which is specified in the cell style.

How to apply this border correctly across the merged cells along with center alignment?

---

Also the list of colours provided by `IndexedColors.COLOR_NAME.getIndex()` is very limited. The list is very unlikely to fulfill the real needs of colours in different cell styles.

Can we use RGB colours in the ss model as we do in the xssf model using `XSSFColor` as follows?

```
XSSFColor commonColor = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
```

Or even something better/different?

PS : I'm using Apache POI 3.10.1.

Comment: What doesn't work if you just [create a XSSF color](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html) and use it?

Comment: In order to use `XSSFColor`, it requires `XSSFCellStyle` like `XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();` that does not work for xls format - `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle`

Comment: Colours are handled very differently by the two file formats, so sadly it isn't possible to have common code for the two for colours. You'll need to test the type of the cell style, then create/assign colours in the format specific way

Comment: Hmm... then it is like creating two separate methods to handle xls and xlsx formats differently/alternatively.

Comment: Yes, there's a handful of cases where the file formats are just too different to wrap up with a common case, and you've found one of them...